# Error in using hadoop commands after mounting hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, fuse

My Hadoop cluster was setup fine and I was able to list the directories in HDFS using
`hadoop fs -ls /user/maddy/`.

Then I installed `hadoop-hdfs-fuse` using the commands below:

`wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/trusty/amd64/cdh5-repository_1.0_all.deb`
`sudo dpkg -i cdh5-repository_1.0_all.deb`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install hadoop-hdfs-fuse`

And finally mounted my HDFS as follows:
`sudo mkdir -p /home/maddy/hdfs`
`sudo hadoop-fuse-dfs dfs://<NAMENODE_HOSTNAME>:<PORT> /home/maddy/hdfs`

The HDFS was successfully mounted. I can run linux commands like:
`ls /home/maddy/hdfs`
And they are working fine. I am able to see all HDFS directories.

But now when I run `hadoop` commands:
`hadoop fs -ls /user/maddy/`

It gives me error - `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell`.

I tried adding in the CLASSPATH the path of my `hadoop-common jar`. But problem didn't solve. Can anybody kindly help me in fixing this?

My Hadoop distribution is Apache one & not cloudera CDH.